# Complex matching across multiple lines

Tags: regex, perl, awk, sed, grep

been searching here and got close but seems like still not quite what i'm trying to do.  eg. please consider following sample test input, the objective is to find matches that span multiple lines that start with line that contains "abc" (print this line), and ends with line that contains "efg" (also print this line), and also print the lines in between.

```
yyabc}
000
iiabc<
    {efg+1}
111
yyabc}
222
 p  {efg+13}
zzz
   z   {efg+243} {}
iii
oooabc>
ooo
```

The closest that came to meeting what i'm looking for is, with zzz as the test input file with above lines,

```
sed -e '/abc/,/efg/!d' zzz
```

, but includes extra lines, that wouldn't mind not being there,

```
yyabc}   <<***** extra
000      <<***** extra
iiabc<
    {efg+1}
yyabc}
222
 p  {efg+13}
oooabc>  <<***** extra
ooo      <<***** extra
```

, thus expected output is,

```
iiabc<
    {efg+1}
yyabc}
222
 p  {efg+13}
```

Besides relying on pcregrep (i have everything else in the linux box), is there a solution that can produce such multiple lines matching?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` is well suited to this task.  If you test input file is called `zzz`, then run:

```
$ awk '/abc/{a=""} /abc/,/efg/{a=a"\n"$0} /efg/{print substr(a,2);a=""}' zzz
iiabc<
    {efg+1}
yyabc}
222
 p  {efg+13}
```

Explanation:

- `/abc/{a=""}`

  Every time that a line containing "abc" is reached, set the variable `a` to an empty string.  (The lines that we want to print will be added to this variable in the next step.)
- `/abc/,/efg/{a=a"\n"$0}`

  Over every range of lines that starts with a line containing `abc` and ends with a line containing `efg`, each line is appended to the variable `a`.
- `/efg/{print substr(a,2);a=""}`

  When the last line in the range is reached, print out `a`.  Because `a` begins with an extra newline character, we use `substr` to remove it.

Without the first step above, the program runs fine but the "extra" lines would be printed.  With the first step included, they are eliminated.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, this works also, and confirmed to work correctly from using the same test input with file size of 2793383645 .

Comment: I like this answer because i can understand it.  Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n '/abc/,/efg/ {
   H
   /efg/ {
      g
:a
      s/^.*\n\(.*abc\)/\1/
      ta
      p
      }
   }' zzz
```

Use of the buffer to catch the part between abc and first efg, than remove any line before the last abc line, finally print the result and continue to rest of text.

Does not work if abc is on the same line as efg with no previous abc from "same" part of text because sed `//,//` work from patterne on one line until pattern on ANOTHER line

Comment: Thanks.  Tried it and it works.  And also tried it against real test input, file size of 2793383645, and works also.

Answer (score 1):

Using a perl one-liner that slurps the entire file:

```
perl -0777 -ne 'print /.*abc.*\n(?:(?!.*(?:abc|efg)).*\n)*.*efg.*\n/g' file.txt
```

Or a line by line buffered solution:

```
perl -ne '
    $b = /abc/ ? $_ : "$b$_";
    print $b if (/abc/ .. /efg/) =~ /E/
  ' file.txt
```

**Switches**:

- `-0777`: Slurp the entire file.
- `-n`: Creates a `while(<>){...}` loop for each “line” in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/abc/,/efg/{/abc/{h;d};H;/efg/{g;p}}' file
```

Used sed in "grep" mode by invoking the `-n` switch. Filter the lines of interest between `abc` and efg`. Use the hold space (HS) to store inclusive lines and then print them out.

Alternative:

```
sed -n '/abc/,/efg/{/abc/h;//!H;/efg/{x;p}}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(.*?abc(?:(?:(?!efg|abc).)|\n)*efg.*$)
```

Try this through perl.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/bA0jG5/11

Comment: @dinan5m3 what did u get?

Comment: Damn, how does this commenting in stackoverflow ??????

Thanks.  I've tried it, and got following,

`$ cat zzz | perl -n000e 'print $& while /(.*?abc(?:(?:(?!efg|abc).)|\n)*efg.*$)/gm'`

Close.  Modified to following, and seems to give the expected result,

`$cat zzz | perl -n000e 'print $& while /(.*?abc(?:(?:(?!efg|abc).)|\n)*efg.*$.*\n)/gm'`

Comment: @dinan5m3 it it answers your question do not forget to mark it as correct.

Comment: But why this perl approach does not work when used with real test input, file size of 2793383645?  But the @NeronLeVelu solution of using sed, using same 2793383645 bytes test input works as expected?

Comment: @dinan5m3 what error do you get....is it some memory issue due to too much of backtracking?

Comment: @NeronLeVelu i don't see any error.  The perl program ends and i get back to the command prompt, thus no output at all.

Comment: @dinan5m3 you might want to check memory usage.It might be going out of memory or something.Dont know whole perl so cant comment how to check that.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward array based awk solution:

```
awk '/abc/ {delete a;j=0;flag=1}
     flag    {a[++j]=$0}
     /efg/ && flag {for (i=1;i<=j;i++){print a[i]};flag=0}' inputfile
```

`/abc/ {delete a;j=0;flag=1}` : When find initial pattern ,delete the array , set counter to zero and turn on the "find" flag.

`flag {a[++j]=$0}` : Store line content when flag is on.

`/efg/ && flag {for (i=1;i<=j;i++){print a[i]};flag=0}`: when end pattern is found and flag on , show the array and turn off flag